# How to query combo box of only current record/row in Access data entry form?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have created a data entry form in Access that uses combobox for entering farmer name. The combobox is used for ease and to make sure only farmers from the list are entered. For ease combo box is re-queried as you type in.
The combobox works well for the first entry but previous farmers' names are vanished when queried for the next row. I think, Access is requerying all dropdowns rather than the current drop-down/combo-box.

[image: Form]

The VBA for the querying drop down is given below:

```
 Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, 
   lookupField As String)
   Dim strSQL As String
     If Len(combo.Text) > 0 Then
    strSQL = defaultSQL & " AND " & lookupField & " LIKE '*" & combo.Text & 
   "*'"
    Else
       strSQL = defaultSQL   'This is the default row source of combo box
   End If
    combo.RowSource = strSQL
    combo.Dropdown

  End Sub

Private Sub Combo137_Change()
    FilterComboAsYouType Me.Combo137, "SELECT  farmer.name,farmer.ID FROM farms INNER JOIN farmer ON 
 farms.ID = farmer.farm_id where farms.ID LIKE" & "'" & Form_Name & "*'", "farmer.name"
 End Sub

Private Sub Combo137_GotFocus()
If Form_Name <> "" Then
FilterComboAsYouType Me.Combo137, "SELECT  farmer.name,farmer.ID FROM farms INNER JOIN farmer ON 
farms.ID = farmer.farm_id where farms.ID LIKE" & "'" & Form_Name & "*'", "farmer.name"
Else
FilterComboAsYouType Me.Combo137, "SELECT  farmer.name,farmer.ID FROM farms INNER JOIN farmer ON 
  farms.ID = farmer.farm_id where farms.ID LIKE" & "'" & "NONE" & "*'", "farmer.name"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _I think, access is requerying all dropdowns rather than the current drop-down/combo-box._ It does. That's by design, as there - though displayed for each row - is one combobox only.

Comment: Why do you even need a combobox to select farmer for a selected farm? A farm can have multiple farmers?

Comment: Yes, a farm can we multiple, combo box will help to filter

Comment: Normally, RowSource would be like: `SELECT ID, [name] FROM farmer WHERE farm_ID = [cbxFarm];` then other properties: ColumnCount 2, ColumnWidths 0";1", BoundColumn 1, AutoExpand Yes, LimitToList Yes.

Comment: Filtering on ID with wildcard doesn't really make sense. `farm_id LIKE '1*'` would return 1, 10, 11, 100, etc. This does not restrict list to a single farm's farmers. Do farms have names?

Comment: But I also want to show the values of farmerNames,  in ComboBox they disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all records will show the same filtered list because there is only one combobox and property settings are reflected in all instances. Filtering a combobox RowSource based on value in another field/control is known as "cascading" or "dependent". Also, your RowSource has alias - value saved is not value displayed. When the list is filtered the display alias will not be available for records that have saved value which has been filtered out. This is a well-known issue of cascading combobox. Options for dealing with:

1. for any form style, only filter the list for new record or when primary value is changed, then reset to full list for existing records
2. for forms in Continuous or Datasheet view, include lookup table in form RecordSource, bind a textbox to descriptive field from lookup table, position textbox on top of combobox, set textbox as Locked Yes and TabStop No

Comment: Yes,then I will have to add two text boxes, one for the farmer_id that will be saved in database, and other for farmer_name that would be just for display.

Comment: The box that holds farmer_id is working fine. But the other box for farmer name is behaving the same way as combo-box. farmer_name box is unboud.

Comment: Private Sub Combo137_AfterUpdate()
   farmer_id.Value = Combo137.Value
   famer_name.Value = Combo137.Text

End Sub

Comment: Why do you need textbox for farmer_ID? Users should not need to see this value. If Farmer_Name textbox is not working then you did not follow guidelines correctly.

Comment: Because it table farmer_id saved.

Comment: Farmer name is just for dispaly

Comment: I understand that. My answer and comments still apply.

Comment: I can bind only one textbox, which is farmer_id box, the other box, farmerName is unbound, how do i update it only once?

Comment: textbox for farmer_ID is required because that field needs to be populated in the table, how can I populate it without text box?

Comment: It's populated with the combobox. What else are you using combobox for? It should be bound to field for saving farmer_id. Carefully read my instructions in answer and comments under your question.