# Non-Index Value Display Issues in Combo Box

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a data entry form for employee information in Access 2016, which contains a fairly standard subform for work history.

In this subform, I have a SQL query to limit the items being pulled. The query itself works fine and is returning the correct results.

It essentially chekcs if the job position is open, (i.e. does not exist in history without an end date), or if it is the same as the current record.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to make the desired text display consistently.

The combobox itself is pulling 3 fields; job_id (index), job_title, and shift (job_title and shift are a unique combination, with job_id just being an autogenerated number).

The actual value being stored is the job_id, but I would like for the combobox to display the job_title after being selected.

This displays correctly when it is first selected, but if I then select a new job_id on a different record (where an event to requery occurs), any item without an end date stops displaying.

I have an event to requery this combobox on getfocus. I am almost positive that the problem has to do with anything missing an end date re-querying, and then not finding itself in the list, and then displaying a blank.(The data itself is not being deleted, just the display)

If I allow the index-column to be displayed, it no longer shows up as a blank, but it only displays the ID number which is not inherently useful to the end user.

If there is anything I can do to clarify please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query combo box of only current record/row in Access data entry form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983037/how-to-query-combo-box-of-only-current-record-row-in-access-data-entry-form)

Comment: Thanks June, that definitely looks to be the issue I'm having. I will try some of those workarounds.